# ios Exception [NSException raise:format:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, key-value-observing

I have this exception, i know it's related to the AVPlayer but i don't exactly understand to what. (something with the observation, but what???)

```
#0  0x36342c64 in objc_exception_throw ()
#1  0x29282d74 in +[NSException raise:format:] ()
#2  0x29f94334 in NSKVODeallocate ()
#3  0x36358d5e in objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) ()
#4  0x2918a25c in CFRelease ()
#5  0x2919eafc in -[__NSSetM dealloc] ()
#6  0x36358d5e in objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) ()
#7  0x27d19d76 in -[AVPlayer dealloc] ()
#8  0x29f94254 in NSKVODeallocate ()
#9  0x36358d5e in objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) ()
#10 0x27d00a3a in -[AVPlayerLayer dealloc] ()
#11 0x29f94254 in NSKVODeallocate ()
#12 0x2c2a73ac in CA::Layer::free_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#13 0x2c2a4052 in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#14 0x2c29decc in CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) ()
#15 0x292495bc in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#16 0x29246c7a in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#17 0x29247082 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#18 0x29195610 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#19 0x29195422 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#20 0x306af0a8 in GSEventRunModal ()
#21 0x2c8df484 in UIApplicationMain ()
#22 0x000f8408 in main at main.m:17
```

thank

*** UPDATE ***

this is the code using AVPlayer and KVO (it's not all of the code, only relevant parts to AVPlayer and KVO. too much code to put all in here....). i have 2 players i'm using. thanks.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*) path
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary*)change
                   context:(void*)context {

/* AVPlayerItem "status" property value observer. */
if (context == MainPlayerStatusObservationContext)
{
    [self syncPlayPauseButtons];

    AVPlayerStatus status = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
    switch (status)
    {
            /* Indicates that the status of the player is not yet known because
             it has not tried to load new media resources for playback */
        case AVPlayerStatusUnknown:
        {
            [self removePlayerTimeObserver];
            [self syncScrubber];

            [self disableScrubber];
            [self disablePlayerButtons];
        }
            break;

        case AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay:
        {
            /* Once the AVPlayerItem becomes ready to play, i.e.
             [playerItem status] == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay,
             its duration can be fetched from the item. */
            SingrDLog(@"item is ready!");
            sMainDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.mPlayer.currentItem.duration);
            //                NSLog(@"SDURATION IS: %f", sDuration);
            [self initScrubberTimer];

            [self enableScrubber];
            [self enablePlayerButtons];

            if (_isMainPlayerPlaying) {
                // make sure the video continues streaming when app goes to backgroud
                [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];
                [self.mPlayer play];
                self.isBuffering = NO;
                [self updatePlayingInfoCenter:self.title :_video.artist_name :@"personal album"];
            }
        }
            break;

        case AVPlayerStatusFailed:
        {
            NSLog(@"name: %@", [mURL lastPathComponent]);
            AVPlayerItem *playerItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
            [self assetFailedToPrepareForPlayback:playerItem.error];
        }
            break;
    }
}

/* AVPlayer "rate" property value observer. */
else if (context == MainPlayerRateObservationContext)
{
    [self syncPlayPauseButtons];
}

/* AVPlayer buffer size observer - update if main player is playing */
else if (context == MainPlayerBufferObservationContext)
{
    NSArray *timeRanges = (NSArray *)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    if (self.isMainPlayerPlaying) {
        [self updateBufferProgressBar:timeRanges];
    }
}

/* AVPlayer "currentItem" property observer.
 Called when the AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:
 replacement will/did occur. */
else if (context == MainPlayerCurrentItemObservationContext)
{
    AVPlayerItem *newPlayerItem = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

    /* Is the new player item null? */
    if (newPlayerItem == (id)[NSNull null])
    {
        [self disablePlayerButtons];
        [self disableScrubber];
    }
    else /* Replacement of player currentItem has occurred */
    {
        /* Set the AVPlayer for which the player layer displays visual output.
         (set it once)
         */
        if (_mPlayerPlaybackViewSet == NO) {
            _mPlayerPlaybackViewSet = YES;
            [self.mPlaybackView setPlayer:mPlayer];
        }

        [self setViewDisplayName];

        /* Specifies that the player should preserve the video’s aspect ratio and
         fit the video within the layer’s bounds. */
        [self.mPlaybackView setVideoFillMode:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];

        [self syncPlayPauseButtons];
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Helper Player KVO
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/* AVHelperPlayerItem "status" property value observer. */
else if (context == HelperPlayerStatusObservationContext)
{
    [self syncHelperPlayPauseButtons];

    AVPlayerStatus status = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
    switch (status)
    {
            /* Indicates that the status of the player is not yet known because
             it has not tried to load new media resources for playback */
        case AVPlayerStatusUnknown:
        {
            [self removeHelperPlayerTimeObserver];
            [self syncHelperScrubber];

            [self disableHelperScrubber];
            [self disableHelperPlayerButtons];
        }
            break;

        case AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay:
        {
            /* Once the AVHelperPlayerItem becomes ready to play, i.e.
             [playerItem status] == AVHelperPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay,
             its duration can be fetched from the item. */
            SingrDLog(@"helper item is ready!");
            sHelperDuration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.mHelperPlayer.currentItem.duration);
            [self initHelperScrubberTimer];

            [self enableHelperScrubber];
            [self enableHelperPlayerButtons];

            if (!_isMainPlayerPlaying) {
                // make sure the video continues streaming when app goes to backgroud
                [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];
                [self.mHelperPlayer play];
                self.isBuffering = NO;
                [self updatePlayingInfoCenter:self.title :_video.artist_name :@"personal album"];
            }
        }
            break;

        case AVPlayerStatusFailed:
        {
            NSLog(@"name: %@", [mHelperURL lastPathComponent]);
            AVPlayerItem *playerItem = (AVPlayerItem *)object;
            [self helperAssetFailedToPrepareForPlayback:playerItem.error];
        }
            break;
    }
}
/* AVHelperPlayer "rate" property value observer. */
else if (context == HelperPlayerRateObservationContext)
{
    [self syncHelperPlayPauseButtons];
}

/* AVHelperPlayer buffer size observer - update if helper player is playing */
else if (context == HelperPlayerBufferObservationContext)
{
    NSArray *timeRanges = (NSArray *)[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    if (!self.isMainPlayerPlaying) {
        [self updateBufferProgressBar:timeRanges];
    }
}

/* AVHelperPlayer "currentItem" property observer.
 Called when the AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:
 replacement will/did occur. */
else if (context == HelperPlayerCurrentItemObservationContext)
{
    AVPlayerItem *newPlayerItem = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

    /* Is the new player item null? */
    if (newPlayerItem == (id)[NSNull null])
    {
        [self disableHelperPlayerButtons];
        [self disableHelperScrubber];
    }
    else /* Replacement of Helper player currentItem has occurred */
    {
        /* Set the AVPlayer for which the Helper player layer displays visual output. */
        if (_mHelperPlayerPlaybackViewSet == NO) {
            _mHelperPlayerPlaybackViewSet = YES;
            [self.mHelperPlaybackView setHelperPlayer:self.mHelperPlayer];
        }

        [self setViewDisplayName];

        /* Specifies that the Helper player should preserve the video’s aspect ratio and
         fit the video within the layer’s bounds. */
        [self.mHelperPlaybackView setHelperVideoFillMode:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];

        [self syncHelperPlayPauseButtons];
    }
}
else
{
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:path ofObject:object change:change context:context];
} }


  (void)prepareToPlayAsset:(AVURLAsset *)asset withKeys:(NSArray *)requestedKeys
  {

for (NSString *thisKey in requestedKeys)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    AVKeyValueStatus keyStatus = [asset statusOfValueForKey:thisKey error:&error];
    if (keyStatus == AVKeyValueStatusFailed)
    {
        NSLog(@"name: %@", [mURL lastPathComponent]);
        [self assetFailedToPrepareForPlayback:error];
        return;
    }
    /* If you are also implementing -[AVAsset cancelLoading], add your code here to bail out    properly in the case of cancellation. */
}

/* Use the AVAsset playable property to detect whether the asset can be played. */
if (!asset.playable)
{
    /* Generate an error describing the failure. */
    NSString *localizedDescription = NSLocalizedString(@"Item cannot be played", @"Item cannot be played description");
    NSString *localizedFailureReason = NSLocalizedString(@"The assets tracks were loaded, but could not be made playable.", @"Item cannot be played failure reason");
    NSDictionary *errorDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               localizedDescription, NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,
                               localizedFailureReason, NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey,
                               nil];
    NSError *assetCannotBePlayedError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"StitchedStreamPlayer" code:0 userInfo:errorDict];

    /* Display the error to the user. */
    [self assetFailedToPrepareForPlayback:assetCannotBePlayedError];

    return;
}

/* At this point we're ready to set up for playback of the asset. */

/* Stop observing our prior AVPlayerItem, if we have one. */
if (self.mPlayerItem)
{
    /* Remove existing player item key value observers and notifications. */

    //[self.mPlayerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kStatusKey];

    NSLog(@"calling NSNotificationCenter remove");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                  object:self.mPlayerItem];
}

/* Create a new instance of AVPlayerItem from the now successfully loaded AVAsset. */
self.mPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

/* Observe the player item "status" key to determine when it is ready to play. */
NSLog(@"call mPlayerItem addObserver");
[self.mPlayerItem addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:kStatusKey
                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                      context:MainPlayerStatusObservationContext];

/* When the player item has played to its end time we'll toggle
 the movie controller Pause button to be the Play button */
NSLog(@"calling NSNotificationCenter add");
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:self.mPlayerItem];

seekToZeroBeforePlay = NO;

/* Create new player, if we don't already have one. */
if (!self.mPlayer)
{
    /* Get a new AVPlayer initialized to play the specified player item. */
    [self setPlayer:[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.mPlayerItem]];

    /* Observe the AVPlayer "currentItem" property to find out when any
     AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem: replacement will/did
     occur.*/
    [self.player addObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:kCurrentItemKey
                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                     context:MainPlayerCurrentItemObservationContext];

    /* Observe the AVPlayer "rate" property to update the scrubber control. */
    [self.player addObserver:self
                  forKeyPath:kRateKey
                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                     context:MainPlayerRateObservationContext];

    /* Observe the asset buffer loaded data. this indicates the buffering size */
    [self.player addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:kBufferLoadedKey
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:MainPlayerBufferObservationContext];
}

/* Make our new AVPlayerItem the AVPlayer's current item. */
if (self.player.currentItem != self.mPlayerItem)
{
    /* Replace the player item with a new player item. The item replacement occurs
     asynchronously; observe the currentItem property to find out when the
     replacement will/did occur*/
    [self.mPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:self.mPlayerItem];

    [self syncPlayPauseButtons];
}

[self.mScrubber setValue:0.0];
SingrDLog(@"set scrub to 0");   }
```

on viewWillDisappear i call this method:

```
#pragma mark - Observers -
  - (void) removeObservers {
if (self.mPlayerItem)
{
    /* Remove existing player item key value observers and notifications. */

    [self.mPlayerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kStatusKey];
    NSLog(@"1 GETTING OUT: calling helper NSNotificationCenter remove");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                  object:self.mPlayerItem];
    self.mPlayerItem = nil;
}
if (self.mHelperPlayerItem)
{
    /* Remove existing player item key value observers and notifications. */

    [self.mHelperPlayerItem removeObserver:self forKeyPath:kStatusKey];
    NSLog(@"2 GETTING OUT: calling helper NSNotificationCenter remove");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                                  object:self.mHelperPlayerItem];
    self.mHelperPlayerItem = nil;
}

// methods check wheter observer exists
[self removePlayerTimeObserver];
[self removeHelperPlayerTimeObserver];
```

}

```
-(void)removePlayerTimeObserver
{
   if (mTimeObserver) {
          NSLog(@"calling mTimeObserver remove");
   [self.mPlayer removeTimeObserver:mTimeObserver];
   mTimeObserver = nil;
   }
  }


-(void)removeHelperPlayerTimeObserver
if (mHelperTimeObserver) {
   NSLog(@"calling mHelperTimeObserver remove");
   self.mHelperPlayer removeTimeObserver:mHelperTimeObserver];
   mHelperTimeObserver = nil;
   }
}
```

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Post the code where you have used the `AVPlayer` that caused this exception. Without the code knowing where the problem occured is hard.If u dont exactly know where this is occuring the put some `try catch blocks` and print the exception to exactly know where it is occuring.. or use `breakpoints`.

Comment: thanks guys, edited question with additional code.